# Average a variable by two others

Tags: sas

Suppose I have the following database:

```
DATA have;
INPUT id date gain;
CARDS;
1 201405 100
2 201504 20
2 201504 30
2 201505 30
2 201505 50
3 201508 200
3 201509 200
3 201509 300
;
RUN;
```

I want to create a new table `want` where the average of the variable `gain` is grouped by `id` and by `date`. The final database should look like this:

```
DATA want;
INPUT id date average_gain;
CARDS;
1 201405 100
2 201504 25
2 201505 40
3 201508 200
3 201509 250
```

I tried to obtain the desired result using the code below but it didn't work:

```
PROC sql;
 CREATE TABLE want as 
 SELECT *,
mean(gain) as average_gain
 FROM have
 GROUP BY id, date
 ORDER BY id, date
 ;
QUIT;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the asterisk that's causing the issue. That will resolve to `id, date, gain`, which is not what you want. ANSI SQL would not allow this type of functionality so it's one way in which SAS differs from other SQL implementation. 
There should be a note in the log about remerging with the original data, which is essentially what's happening. The summary values are remerged to every line.

To avoid this, list your group by fields in your query and it will work as expected.

```
    PROC sql;
    CREATE TABLE want as 
     SELECT id, date,
     mean(gain) as average_gain
     FROM have
     GROUP BY id, date
     ORDER BY id, date
     ;
    QUIT;
```

I will say, in general, PROC MEANS is usually a better option because:

- calculate for multiple variables & statistics without need to list them all out multiple times
- can get results at multiple levels, for example totals at grand total, id and group level
- not all statistics can be calculated within PROC MEANS
- supports variable lists so you can shortcut reference long lists without any issues